# Node.js Primeiros passos, não sei como começar

Tags: javascript, node.js

Venho me dedicando ao JavaScript a algum tempo, procurando várias maneiras de aprender, recentemente me deparei com as funções callback, geralmente utilizadas quando se utiliza de javascript em um servidor ao invés de local (corrija-me se eu estiver errado).

Encontrei uma série de exercícios para aprender a simular um servidor com o node, baixei todos os arquivos e agora pretendo começar a programar nele. No entanto os exercícios que estou seguindo pra aprender de maneira passo a passo, não está claro pra mim ainda, segue o que é sugerido:

[image: Exercício de Node JavaScript]

O que ele quer dizer no "o servidor deve responder ao `/file/*` URI? E então mapear num local folder. Não consigo entender o que eu devo fazer pra iniciar a trabalhar com isso. Se alguém poder dar uma explicação mais clara, de maneira que um iniciante possa entender e passar a desenvolver algo, ou até um código genérico como exemplo, também seria muito produtivo aos estudos. Muito obrigado.

Tudo que fiz até agora é:

```
 var http = require('http');

function onrequest(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("Hello World\n");
}

var server = http.createServer(onrequest);
server.listen(8000);

console.log("Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo que pode ajudar https://adrianmejia.com/building-a-node-js-static-file-server-files-over-http-using-es6/

Comment: Excelente para iniciantes de Nodejs: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ_KhUnlXUPtbtLwaxxUxHqvcNQndmI4B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa funçäo onrequest vai ser chamada cada vez que houver um pedido ao servidor.

Tens dois parâmetros nessa função, o primeiro é o objeto do pedido (`request`) e nele tens uma propriedade chamada `url`. Isso quer dizer que quando o servidor receber um pedido ele vai chamar essa função e passar como argumento um objeto `request` onde podes ler o `request.url`.

Por exemplo: se chamares `console.log(request.url);` dentro dessa função e no browser colocares `http://localhost:8000/file.text1.js` vais ver no terminal o url pedido ou seja `/file.text1.js`.

Então aí podes colocar lógica para filtrar as rotas que queres com RegExp. Por exemplo, se a rota começar com `/file/` ir ler um ficheiro a uma diretoria específica pode ser feito assim:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const rootFolder = __dirname;

function onrequest(request, response) {
  console.log(request.url);
  const isFileFolder = request.url.match(/^\/file\/*/);
  if (isFileFolder) {
    const fileName = request.url.slice(5); // remover "/file"
    const data = fs.readFileSync(rootFolder + fileName, "utf8");
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end(data);
    return;
  }

  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("Hello World\n");
}

const server = http.createServer(onrequest);
server.listen(8000);

console.log("Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Testei este exemplo que escrevi da seguinte maneira: coloquei este código dentro de um ficheiro chamado `server.js` e depois no browser chamei `http://localhost:8000/file/server.js`. Isso retornou o conteúdo do `server.js`.

Agora só precisas de adaptar ao teu caso específico e mudar o valor de `rootFolder`.